# date format changed strange way

Tags: pandas, date

my df['date'] is format as

```
pandas.core.series.Series
```

and I change the date format

```
df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
```

but the date changed to the strange format

```
20160101  -> 1970-01-01 00:00:00.020160101
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas try `'guess'` format of datetimes and sometimes failed. So here if all datetimes has format `YYYYMMDD` add parameter `format='%Y%m%d'` for correct parsing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['20160101', '20160104']})
df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format='%Y%m%d')
print (df)
       date  date_time
0  20160101 2016-01-01
1  20160104 2016-01-04
```

EDIT: In some last pandas versions (tested in pandas 0.25.1) your solution should working correct:

```
df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
print (df)
       date  date_time
0  20160101 2016-01-01
1  20160104 2016-01-04
```